Magnetic Sensor to GPS heading in Gazebo?
I have a magnetometer sensor in Gazebo running, but want to convert it to a GPS heading.  I additionally have the navsatfix plugin working (Would be nice if there was a heading in that somehow as well).   Does anyone know how to get the GPS heading, or if there is a plugin that generates NMEA sentences?

can you have a GPS heading when you are not moving?

Good point.  I would think the mag sensor can adjust to earths field though?  A compass can...
